# Problem with shapefile - labelling polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I am trying to produce a map of Nakuru, a region in Kenya, which has its subcounties labelled. i am not fussy - this could be with numbers, colours or on the map.

I am using this shape file:
https://data.amerigeoss.org/dataset/kenya-sub-counties/resource/bf1919f7-d908-444f-b5c4-821573e29189?inner_span=True

The polygons are odd shapes and so their centre point doesn't result in a nice picture, i.e.

```
kenyasubcounties<-  readOGR( 
  dsn=  "ke_subcounty" , 
  layer="ke_subcounty",
  verbose=FALSE)

nakuru<- kenyasubcounties[kenyasubcounties$county  %in% c("Nakuru"), ]

centroids <- getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(nakuru)


labels<- as.data.frame( nakuru$subcounty)
centroids <- as.data.frame(centroids)
centroids<- cbind(centroids, labels)
centroids<- centroids %>%  rename (labs = "nakuru$subcounty") %>% 
            mutate(labs = str_replace(labs, "  Sub County", ""))
# need to sort out gilgil and bahati

centroids$labs[centroids$labs == "Gilgil Sub County" ]<- "Gilgil"
centroids$labs[centroids$labs == "Kuresoi North"   ]<- "Kuresoi \n North"
centroids$labs[centroids$labs == "Kuresoi South"  ]<- "Kuresoi \n South"
centroids$labs[centroids$labs == "Nakuru North"  ]<- "Bahati"
centroids$labs[centroids$labs == "Nakuru West"  ]<- "Nakuru \n West"
centroids$labs[centroids$labs == "Nakuru East"  ]<- "Nakuru \n East"



plot(nakuru, col =  "#66C2A5")
text(centroids$V1, centroids$V2, centroids$labs, offset=0, cex=1)
```

[image: map of nakuru with horrid labels]

the same happens if I try to number them

```
plot(nakuru, col =  "#66C2A5")
text(centroids$V1, centroids$V2, centroids$num, offset=0, cex=1)
```

[image: nakuru with numbers as labels]

I then tries to use ggplot, but using the following code I get the error:
"Regions defined for each Polygons
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'subcounty' not found"

```
ggplot(data = nakuru ) +
  geom_polygon( aes( x = long, y = lat, fill= subcounty , group = group), color="white")
```

this persists with different iterations.

Any help very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with sf and Tidyverse / ggplot, this should get you bit closer, `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` let you control the position of each individual text. Though to fit Nakuru East to anywhere close to its borders you have to scale up the output image (a lot) and/or decrease font size. There's also https://yutannihilation.github.io/ggsflabel/index.html that provides few extra geoms for labelling sf data in ggplot, worth checking out if installing packages from github is also OK.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ke_subcounty <- st_read("ke_subcounty/ke_subcounty.shp") 
ke_subcounty %>%  
  filter(county == "Nakuru") %>% 
  mutate(sub = str_remove(subcounty, "\\s+Sub County"), 
         sub = str_replace(sub, "\\s","\n")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey95", color = "grey90") +
  geom_sf_text(
    aes(label = sub), 
              # KS Na  NE NN    Su Gi Mo KN    NW Nj   Ro
    nudge_x = c(0, 0, .2, 0,    0, 0, 0, 0,    0, 0, -.06),
    nudge_y = c(0, 0,  0, 0, -.06, 0, 0, -.05, 0, 0, -.05),
    fun.geometry = sf::st_centroid) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>